# Consequences of coolant phase change in radiator

Tags: coolant, radiator, formula

Im a Freshman at my Institute in India. In the application form for the Institutes Formula Student Team, I came across these 2 questions, which I'm stumped by. Ive searched for the answers but cannot seem to find them anywhere. The questions are:

1.If a phase change occurs at some point in the radiator, what
consequences are we looking at ?

2.This is a common occurrence in large vehicles. How is it taken care of ?

My guess is that the radiator would fail? If perhaps the coolant froze then it would lead to all coolant being dumped out the overflow pipe? If it boils then because of ineffective cooling the engine overheats? As for the second part I have no clue. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot

The motor is an EMRAX 228 Medium Voltage Liquid Cooled variant if that helps

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is the context of the 2nd question? Does it refer to the first question, or is it asking in general for something which happens commonly in large vehicles?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 the 2nd question as I understand says phase changes occur in the radiator quite commonly in large vehicles, and asks how it is managed/solved/avoided. I hope that clarifies it :)

Comment: The problem is, to my experience, if the cooling system is setup right in the first place, it's not common place. Coolant can be in three different phase states: frozen; liquid; gas (plasma doesn't come into play here). Unless things get *very* cold, regular coolant of 50/50 mix will go down to about -40° (C or F take your pick) and up to about 265°F under pressure. Liquid is the normal state. Gas happens after the 265° mark, but as long as it's circulating and going through the rad with a fan to cool it, there's no issue of that. Again, "common" is not a word I'd use.

Comment: Understood. That also explains why I couldnt find any cases of such problems on the internet. But could you give some insight as to what might happen considering a hypothetical phase change in the radiator?

Comment: What happens when the liquid freezes? It expands and things burst. What happens when liquid goes gaseous? This usually occurrs because it's over heated, so the radiator cap blows off the radiator and the engine (if not shut down soon enough) will go nuclear and seize.

Comment: Actually, "frozen pipes" usually burst when some water is trapped between two plugs of ice that are frozen onto the pipe walls. Otherwise, the liquid just moves out of the way as the ice forms (and that might overflow the radiator cap, of course). Most antifreeze does not have a sharp freeze like water freezing to ice, but goes through a "mushy" stage where the pressure can equalize though the whole cooling system to  avoid bursts.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a phase change of coolant in an engine is either the conversion of liquid coolant to gas (boiling), or the conversion of liquid coolant to solid (freezing).

Most liquid cooled internal combustion engines are water based coolant systems.  And an unfortunate characteristic of water is that when it freezes (solidifies) there is an increase in volume.  This increase involves potentially high forces and can crack engine blocks, split open radiators and cause coolant plumbing and cabin heaters to fail.  To counteract this, ethylene or propylene glycol are commonly used.  Mixtures will depress the freezing point and have the side benefit of increasing the boiling point.  A common mixture is 50/50 ethylene glycol and water.

If an engine has been subjected to freezing, there may be structural damage to hard components.  If an engine has been subjected to overheating and water (and other additives) have boiled off, then softer components like heater hoses, radiator hoses and even radiator and heater cores may be damaged, and need replacement.

Preventative measures include periodic cooling system inspections, and measuring the concentration of antifreeze agents with the water.  This is done with hydrometers to measure the density (commonly a float in a drawing tube.  It can also more accurately be measured with a portable refractometer.  Both are relatively inexpensive, although the refractometer is just a little more difficult to master.